# virtualenv: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04, pyramid

I'm using `virtualenv` and developing some pyramid applications. When I try to use

```
../bin/python setup.py
```

I get:

> bash: ../bin/python/: Too many levels of symbolic links

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `pythonsetup.py` written by you? Show the codes.

Comment: Sorry `pythonsetup.py` is a typo. I'll edit. Its actually the `setup.py` file created by pyramid.

Comment: You get this error also, if you try ``virtualenv .nox/xxx`` and xxx exists already. To enter an existing environment, do ``source .nox/xxx/bin/activate`` .

Answer (score 1):

Hi~ i just encountered the same issue as you, i believe if you remove the 'env' file, and activate virtualenv again, this problem will be solved. It may not be the best solution but it could be a quick method.

Answer (score 0):

You've omitted a space from your command.

From the directory in which the file `setup.py` is located, the command should be `$VENV/bin/python setup.py`.

Although [Pyramid installation documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html) recommends virtualenv, it does not recommend activating the virtualenv. Instead it is much preferable to set an environment variable to the path of the virtualenv for your project.

`export VENV=~/projects/myproject/env`

Which then makes it easy to set up a virtualenv.

`virtualenv $VENV`

And correctly execute commands from any directory in your project.

`$VENV/bin/python setup.py`

Comment: Actually I set the VENV variable like you did.
Are you suggesting that I should run the app without activating the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes. If you have activated the virtualenv, then deactivate it, then try the command `$VENV/bin/python setup.py` again.

Comment: My project folder is not in the home directory. So I set 
`export VENV=/var/www/pyramid/venv`  

Then  `$VENV/bin/python setup.py`
  while inside my project directory.

Comment: TBH, your best option is to delete your project and start clean, then follow the step by step instructions in [Installing Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html) There are too many places where you can run off the rails: incorrectly installed Python, mixing pip and setuptools while installing software, activating a virtualenv, to name a few.

Comment: Guess that's what I have to do now. Thank you for all your help :)